# Cast IList to List

Tags: c#, list, casting, ilist

I am trying to cast `IList` type to `List` type but I am getting error every time.

```
List<SubProduct> subProducts= Model.subproduct;
```

`Model.subproduct` returns `IList<SubProduct>`.

Comment: it's best to program against the interface (IList) instead of the implimentation (List).
It's an unneeded cast to go to List.
You now have to add error handling if on the off chance an implementation of IList, which is not a List, enteres that code path.

Comment: Yeah, but `IList` doesn't have stuff that `List` has, for example `AddRange`

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Try

```
List<SubProduct> subProducts = new List<SubProduct>(Model.subproduct);
```

or

```
List<SubProduct> subProducts = Model.subproducts as List<SubProduct>;
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but is there a reason that you want to deal with a List instead of IList? Most of the times using IList is a better choice.

Comment: IList<SubProduct> subProducts= Model.subproduct;

Comment: @KeithRousseau I ran into the issue when needing to utilize the AddRange() method.

Comment: The second option is not safe, because it assumes that `Model.subproducts` is already of type `List<SubProduct>` under the covers. If it's a different implementation of `IList<SubProduct>`, such as `ReadOnlyCollection<SubProduct>`, it will silently return null and will likely cause a very confusing `NullReferenceException` later in the program execution. And really, if we know that it's always going to be a `List<T>`, then what's the point of returning an `IList<T>` in the first place?

Answer (score 35):

How about this:

```
List<SubProduct> subProducts = Model.subproduct.ToList();
```

Comment: Be aware that ToList() creates a copy with possible performance and memory impact.

Answer (score 19):

In my case I had to do this, because none of the suggested solutions were available:

```
List<SubProduct> subProducts = Model.subproduct.Cast<SubProduct>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
List<SubProduct> subProducts= (List<SubProduct>)Model.subproduct;
```

The implicit conversion failes because `List<>` implements `IList`, not viceversa. So you can say `IList<T> foo = new List<T>()`, but not `List<T> foo = (some IList-returning method or property)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an IList containing interfaces, you can cast it like this:

List to IList

```
List<Foo> Foos = new List<Foo>(); 
IList<IFoo> IFoos = Foos.ToList<IFoo>();
```

IList to List

```
IList<IFoo> IFoos = new List<IFoo>();
List<Foo> Foos = new List<Foo>(IFoos.Select(x => (Foo)x));
```

This assumes `Foo` has `IFoo` interfaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ProjectResources> list = new List<ProjectResources>();        
IList<ProjectResources> obj = `Your Data Will Be Here`;
list = obj.ToList<ProjectResources>();
```

This Would Convert IList Object to List Object.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers all recommend to use AddRange with an IList.

A more elegant solution that avoids the casting is to implement an extension to IList to do the job.

In VB.NET:

```vb
<Extension()>
Public Sub AddRange(Of T)(ByRef Exttype As IList(Of T), ElementsToAdd As IEnumerable(Of T))
   For Each ele In ElementsToAdd
      Exttype.Add(ele)
   Next
End Sub
```

And in C#:

```cs
public void AddRange<T>(this ref IList<T> Exttype, IEnumerable<T> ElementsToAdd)
{
    foreach (var ele in ElementsToAdd)
    {
        Exttype.Add(ele);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public async Task<List<TimeAndAttendanceShift>> FindEntitiesByExpression(Expression<Func<TimeAndAttendanceShift, bool>> predicate)
{
    IList<TimeAndAttendanceShift> result = await _dbContext.Set<TimeAndAttendanceShift>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync<TimeAndAttendanceShift>();
    return result.ToList<TimeAndAttendanceShift>();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This is the best option to cast/convert list of generic object to list of string.

```
object valueList;
List<string> list = ((IList)valueList).Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: valueList must be list of object