# Dealing with an invalid cast - IList to List<Type>

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using C# 4.0 and I have a problem with reflection and casting. I've read through a few threads on StackOverflow and none that I've tried so far have given a solution that works for me.

The problem: I have a class, Character, which is derived from another class, called GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID. I have a list of Characters (as in, type List) and I want to get them through reflection as a

```
List<GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID>.
```

So far I use the following:

```
(IList)p.GetValue(context, null);
```

This will get me the list in question, no problem, but as an IList. What I want, as I said, is List.

So I've tried this:

```
(List<GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID>)p.GetValue(context, null);
```

Now I know, for purposes of testing, that the list is Characters (List(Character)) and Character derives from GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID.

When I run the line above, I get the following:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GameSystem.DataModel.Character]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WPF_MVVM_GenericBaseDLL.Data_Objects.GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID]'.

I must be going mad because I've checked about ten times. Character derives from GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID.

I have tried this too:

```
IList propertyList = (IList)p.GetValue(context, null);
List<GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID> newList = new List<GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID>(propertyList);
```

This tells me that "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'"

I also tried this:

```
IList propertyList = (IList)p.GetValue(context, null);
List<GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID> newList = propertyList as List<GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID>;
```

I don't get an error here, but 'newList' is null.

These are the suggestions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207341/cast-ilist-to-list?noredirect=1&lq=1), but no luck so far.

I hope I'm just missing something simple. And please, no, I can't just go ahead and use IList. I have tried that too, but I have code further along that requires the use of

```
List<GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID>.
```

Comment: `List<T>` is not covariant so a `List<Character>` is not a `List<GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID>`. A `List<Character>` is an `IEnumerable<GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID>` though so you can do `var newList = new List<GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID>((IEnumerable<GenericDataObjectWithUniqueID>)p.GetValue(context, null));`

Comment: Just a note : before you use reflection you probably should explore more robust and performant ways to solve your problems first.